# Trying to add multiple selections together from a list on a website

Tags: javascript, html, math, web, calculation

```js
$(function() {
  var fields = $('#form1 :input').change(calculate)
  $("#form1 option").text(function(i, t) {
    if (this.value !== "0")
      return t + " - " + this.value
  })

  function calculate() {
    var price = 0;
    fields.each(function() {
      price += +$(this).val();
    })
    $('#price').html(price.toFixed(0));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <select name="DMA1" multiple id="DMA1">
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                 <option value="3">3</option>
                 <option value="4">4</option>
              </select>
  </p>
  </p>
</form>
Total: <u id="price"></u>
<p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>
```

I found an example I was able to get working where I can have multiple drop-down lists add their values together. That page/code is working fine.

I have been unable to adapt it so you can shift-select (or command-select on mac) and have it Total the values in the Total field at the bottom of the page.

My current code is below and any assistance would be appreciated. I have been searching online for some time now and can't seem to find what I am looking for. Closest I could find is to have multiple drop-downs (mentioned above)

Here is the breakdown:

Javascript

```
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(function () {
         var fields = $('#form1 :input').change(calculate)
         $("#form1 option").text(function(i,t){
             if (this.value!=="0") 
                 return t + " - " + this.value
         })

         function calculate() {
             var price = 0;
             fields.each(function () {
                 price += +$(this).val();
             })
             $('#price').html(price.toFixed(0));
         }
     })

  </script>
```

Body

```
   <body>
        <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
           <p>
              <select name="DMA1" multiple id="DMA1">
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                 <option value="3">3</option>
                 <option value="4">4</option>
              </select>
           </p>
           </p>  
        </form>
        Total: <u id="price"></u>
        <p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to calculate against the `<select>` element. The `fields` variable was incorrectly set. Set it to the options as the attached.

```js
$(function() {
  var fields = $('option');
  $('#form1 :input').change(calculate)
  $("#form1 option").text(function(i, t) {
    if (this.value !== "0")
      return t + " - " + this.value
  })

  function calculate() {
    var price = 0;
    fields.each(function() {
      if (this.selected) {
        price += +$(this).val();
      }
    })
    $('#price').html(price.toFixed(0));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <select name="DMA1" multiple id="DMA1">
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                 <option value="3">3</option>
                 <option value="4">4</option>
              </select>
  </p>
  </p>
</form>
Total: <u id="price"></u>
<p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a bunch, exactly what I needed! I feel a little silly for missing that but I am still fairly new to the javascript / programming side of things

Comment: All good. glad to help when OP is focused and provides good example!

Comment: Oh, and I forgot the mention the check for `selected` inside your loop.